# Setting exact width of div in pixels?

Tags: gwt

I'm seeing strange behavior on an iphone 4s device when it comes to specifying sizes of a div in pixel units.

My iphone is 980 pixels wide in portrait orientation.

As a first test, I just created a plain html implementation. This works exactly as expected - the div takes up the entire width of my screen, but is no wider:

```
<body>
  <div style="width:980px; height: 30px; background-color: red;"></div>
</body>
```

Now in GWT, I try the same thing (at least I think it's equivalent):

```
FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
fp.setWidth("980px");
fp.setHeight("30px");
fp.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");
RootPanel.get().add(fp);
```

but when loaded on my iphone, the div appears to be twice the width of the screen. Is GWT doing some kind of scaling automatically? I know the iphone 4S is a retina display, therefore it has a 2x pixel ratio. Is it something related to that?

I can't examine the output html on my iphone, but when I look at the GWT version in firefox, I can see GWT is indeed outputting the 980px size I specified:

```
// What GWT outputs - looks the same as my hand-written version:
<div style="width: 980px; height: 30px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

So why would the GWT version render the div 2x as wide?

------ Update ----------

As Woojah recommended, I tried via a style definition:

```
.sanityTest {
width: 980px;
height: 30px;
background-color: green;
}

FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
fp.setStyleName("sanityTest");
```

but still the same behavior - on the iphone 4s screen, the div is twice the width of the display. The dom looks exactly the same as in my handwritten version. The size behaves correctly on a non-retina device.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommmend you try the following:

1. do:

   `getElement().getStyle.setWidth(x,  Style.Unit.PX);
   getElement().getStyle.setHeight(y,  Style.Unit.PX);`

That is the equivalent for your
`style="width:980px; height: 30px; background-color: red;`

1. Another alternative is to defina inside your css stylesheed a class like
   `.yourCss
   {
   width:980px; height: 30px; background-color: red;
   }`

and then in your code do `flowPanel.setStyleName("yourCss");`

Comment: Good idea, just tried that but sadly still same behavior, the div is 2x the width it should be.

Comment: oof so it looks like mobile safari was automatically zooming in on my gwt page implementation, but not on the hand-written one. Can't believe I missed that this whole time.